# Show alert if nothing is found from a ResultSet in JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

This code is to show an error after a button is clicked. What the `buttonclick` does is check if the username and password correspond with the username and password in the database.

IF true it will show the next scene. if false I want to show that error I made. Showing the next scene works fine, showing the error doesn't.

This is my code :

```
public Pane createLogin() throws SQLException {
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(10);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

    Button login = new Button("Login!");
    TextField usernameField = new TextField();
    usernameField.setPromptText("Username");
    PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
    passwordField.setPromptText("Password");
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("ERROR");
    alert.setHeaderText("OH SNAP");
    alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");

    login.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            String username = usernameField.getText();
            String password = passwordField.getText();
            String query = "Select * from user WHERE username ='" + username + "' and password ='" + password + "'";
            ResultSet rs = null;
            System.out.println("hahah:" + username);
            try {
                rs = dataBase.executeQuery(query);
                dataBase.executeDataRowQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if (username.equals(rs.getString("username"))) {
                        if (password.equals(rs.getString("password"))) {
                            switchScreen(createOverview());
                        } else{
                            alert.showAndWait();
                        }
                    } else{
                        alert.showAndWait();
                    }
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
    gridPane.add(new Label("Username: "), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(usernameField, 0, 1);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Password: "), 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(passwordField, 1, 1);

    gridPane.add(new Label("Login!"), 2, 0);
    gridPane.add(login, 2, 1);

    return gridPane;
}
```

Comment: [Little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) would be so proud.. if there's no record, you don't enter the while because rs.next() returns false!

Answer (score 1):

Since `ResultSet.next` returns if there exist more rows, you could just do

```
if (rs.next()) {
    switchScreen(createOverview());
} else {
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

or alternatively use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` and check the first column in the first row:

```
if (rs.next() && rs.getInt(1) > 0)
    ...
```

**Note:** I won't elaborate on SQL injection or other serious security issues like allowing to read password and username info...